# Windows VMWare + VPN + Ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, vpn

I have Ubuntu host that has a VMWare running Windows XP.
If I connect to a VPN from my Windows XP, then will that connection be available to my host Ubuntu as well?

Regards
Balaji D Loganathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No your connection on the virtual Windows XP machine will not be directly available on the phyiscal Ubuntu installation.

The host system (phyisical machine which is running the virtual machines) does not have access to the network connections of a VM.